# Explanation of a formula to calculate the zenith distance of sun and moon

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, notation, spherical-geometry

I am studying tidal accelerations and referring to a well known paper by I M Longman :
Formulas for computing.." J Geophys Research 64 (12) Dec 1959.

At Eq 12 he writes a term "1336.rev". The quantity rev is not defined and it's not the product r.e.v. I looked up where he got the information and rev is also not defined in the source paper by P Schureman "A manual..." . Schureman got it from yet another archaic paper which I cannot find.

I should be grateful if anyone could enlighten me. Have I to start from scratch to get the time
dependence of the zenith distances of sun and moon ?

Schureman "A manual... predic tion of tides" US coast and Geodetic Survey, Spec Publication 98 (1924)

David Morley

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rev. = revolutions; 1336 revolutions (more precisely 1336.85136) is the mean sidereal motion of the moon in a Julian century (= 36525 days). Since 1 rev. = $2\pi$ radians, and you can ignore this number when calculating the longitude modulo $2\pi$.

Here is a screenshot from the [Manual of Harmonic Analysis and Prediction of Tides](https://books.google.nl/books?id=jI8TAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is the source of Longman's formulas.

[image]